# jquery to act as href while passing ajax value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here's the situation:

I need to load a php script into a modal window. In order to do that, I need to make the button that loads the modal window an a tag with the href pointing to that script. Prior to loading that script however, I need Ajax to send information to that php script in order to run a query. The results of that query is whats displayed in that modal window. The issue im running into is when the button is clicked, both the href request and ajax request are processed and the page comes back empty(looking at the console, saw two xhr requests, one with the Ajax information and the other with just the name of the php file(which I think is the href request)). Did a var_dump for the $_POST and got array size=0

Here is the button code:

```
   a href='extschedule.php' type='submit' id='editButton' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm user editButton'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editModal' data-id='$id'
```

Here is my ajax code:

```
    $('.editButton').click(function(e){

    var getid = $(this).data('id');

    $.post('extschedule.php', {getid: getid});
    e.preventDefault();
```

Here is whats in my console when I select the button:

```
 XHR Loaded (extschedule.php - 200 OK - 3.119945526123047ms - 953B)
VM1660:3 **http://localhost/extschedule.php?getid=146**
VM1661:3 Object {startedDateTime: "2015-01-26T17:26:59.392Z", time: 3.119945526123047, request: Object, response: Object, cache: Object…}
VM1663:3 XHR Loaded (extschedule.php - 200 OK - 13.669967651367188ms - 1.077KB)
VM1664:3 **http://localhost/extschedule.php**
VM1665:3 Object {startedDateTime: "2015-01-26T17:26:59.398Z", time: 13.669967651367188, request: Object, response: Object, cache: Object…}
```

Im fairly new to ajax and php but my guess is that both requests to the same php file is causing issues with the results. Again I need to pass the value of the button selected while also load the php script into the modal window via href. Can someone help me work though this or suggest a different strategy on accomplishing this goal?

P.S. - I thought about editing the url for the href to include the getid set to a variable depending on the data-id value. It worked for the first one but if I exit the modal window and click on another user, it will not load the new value.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent both the ajax request and the submit from happening, change the type="submit" to type="button" and forget the href.

It looks like in your example that the onclick event is already making the request to 'extschedule.php' and you don't want to submit the form if you're making an ajax call.

A submit transfers control to another instance of a page and ajax makes a request to the server which returns a result back to the calling page.